# Bugzilla Extension: Modifying "Assigned To" field using set_assigned_to in bug_end_update

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I am trying to modify the Assigned To field on a bug (to Reporter) when the status is set to RESOLVED.  My current code looks like this:

```
sub bug_end_of_update
{
    my ($self, $args) = @_; 

    my $bug = $args->{ 'bug' };
    my $changes = $args->{ 'changes' };
    # Check if the status has changed
    if ( $changes->{ 'bug_status' } )
    {
        my ($old_status, $new_status) = @{ $changes->{ 'bug_status' } };
        # Check if the bug status has been set to RESOLVED
        if ( $new_status eq "RESOLVED" )
        {
            # Change Assignee to the original Reporter of the Bug.
            $bug->set_assigned_to( <reporter obj> );

            # Add to changes for tracking
            $changes->{ 'assigned_to' } = [ <assigned obj>, <reporter obj> ];
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for two things:
1) In bug_end_of_update how do I get the reporter user object and the assigned to user object?
2) Is the changes array looking for user objects or just login info?

Thanks!

Comment: Found http://bugzilla.glob.com.au/irc/a=date&h=&s=+4+Feb+2011&e=+4+Feb+2011 which gave some insight into the changes I needed to make to get this all up and running.  First I was using the wrong Hook because in bug_end_of_update the DB had already been written to.  So I used object_end_of_set_all adjusted the parameters and everything worked.  The user objects where just the login info $bug->reporter->login.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
sub bug_end_of_update {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

    my ($bug, $old_bug, $timestamp, $changes) = @$args{qw(bug old_bug timestamp changes)};

    if ($changes->{bug_status}[1] eq 'RESOLVED') {      # Status has been changed to RESOLVED
        $bug->set_assigned_to($bug->reporter->login);   # re-assign to Reporter
        $bug->update();
    }
}
```

However, it updates the bug twice (since bug_end_of_update is called once the database has already been updated).

A better solution is:

```
sub object_end_of_set_all {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

    my $object = $args->{'object'};

    if ($object->isa('Bugzilla::Bug')) {
        if ($object->{'bug_status'} eq 'RESOLVED') {            # Bug has been RESOLVED
            $object->{'assigned_to'} = $object->{'reporter_id'};    # re-assign to Reporter
        }
    }
}
```